# Will the stimulus bill deduct from the $1200 check after being laid off?

Tags: united-states, taxes, stimulus

I recently got laid off. In my 2019 tax return, it will convey that I made $110k that year.

Will the stimulus bill deduct from the $1200 check?

Comment: Are you filing as Married Filing Jointly (and if so, is $110k your joint income)? Or some other filing status? Have you filed your 2019 tax return yet? If not, what was your income on your 2018 tax return?

Comment: @user102008 I have been filing single. And yes I have filed for both 2019 and 2018 tax returns

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have filed your 2019 tax return as Single and your 2019 Adjusted Gross Income (AGI) was more than $99,000, you will not get a stimulus check. (Though if your 2020 AGI is less than $99,000, you can still claim credit against your 2020 taxes.)

Comment: So to clarify, if I got paid less than $99,000 in 2020, I would get it through my 2020 tax returns?

Comment: @user: Yes, I believe so. There are two parts: the tax credit, which applies to the 2020 tax year, and the *advance* of the 2020 tax credit given to you as a check, which is the same amount as the tax credit, but determined based on your 2019 (or 2018) tax return. I believe the advance tax credit will be reconciled with the actual tax credit you should get for 2020 when you file your 2020 taxes.